# While appending a UUID field in to a list it also storig the type of the filed

Tags: django, list, django-views

I am having a model and it having a uuid field

```
public_id = models.UUIDField(
    unique=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

I am getting an issue

while filtering I am getting a query set like this <obj1,obj2, obj3...>

I am looping through it and saving the public_id in a single list like this

```
associated_elements = list()
for i in query_set:
      associated_elements.append(i.public_id)
print(associated_elements)
```

I am getting output like this

```
 [UUID('a3d69af6-9678-4c1a-8adf-3b9f3600c3b5'), UUID('c0cc4cbd-9b79-4e04-bbc2-dcfb52a9e3de'), UUID('86cd21a5-0833-4b46-8dd8-bf730a3014ee'), UUID('70596f50-2e00-44e9-9795-fce13d33fdbb'), UUID('e60c88b3-1066-4ddd-bab6-7a33a84dd998')]
```

But I need an output in this format

```
['7e254d14-488a-45ed-8712-fe1a339d6c28', '40949d78-8252-4087-b69e-2143915b2317']
```

Is there any way for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below,

```
associated_elements = list()
for i in query_set:
      associated_elements.append(str(i.public_id))
print(associated_elements)
```

Reference:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html